# How to add key in along with array object in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

Here is my a resultant array and now I want to add extra key along with **current** key.
tried .**push is not a function**

```
aa[0]['new_key'] = 'blah';    // is not working
```

My array is looks like.

```
 var aa =  [
        {
          "main": "56d940bb2b5916181d0906e2",
          "current": 6544
        }
      ]
```

And my original code is using mongoDB query.

```
connection.modal.find( { 'user_id' : user_id }, { 'abc.def' : true}, function ( err, result ) {

            if ( !err ) {

                if( result.length ) {

                    result[0]['abc'].def[0]['new_key']  = 'blah';
                    response['success'] = true;
                    response['result'] = result[0]['abc'].def;
                    response['msg'] = 'data fetch';
                    res.json(response);
                } else {

                    response['success'] = false;
                    response['result'] = '';
                    response['msg'] = 'No record found';
                    res.json(response);
                }
            } else {

                response['success'] = false;
                response['result'] = '';
                response['msg'] = 'Error';
                res.json(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working?"

Comment: btw, there is no push involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also get same problem a lot i resolved this issue by using this

```
connection.modal.find( { 'user_id' : user_id }, { 'abc.def' : true}, function ( err, result ) {
 /// ADD THIS LINE /////////
result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
 ....
```